# Error on google actions "App testaction-fff11 was not found. The app preview may have expired"

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, google-home

I followed the steps illustrated in documentation:
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications

But in the last step when I try to send a notification the api "https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send" reply with this error.

```
{ code: 404,
 message: 'App testaction-fff82 was not found. The app preview may have expired.',
 status: 'NOT_FOUND' } }
```

I don't understand just what is not there.

Permission is granted, intent is configurated, the credentials work, the application is the right one.

Has anyone happened to the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Self answer: as described [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#target) the "locale" field must be specified